# Track Properties in Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

[Tracked Properties of Logic Apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ookJ1.png)

I am trying to track properties in a Logic App workflow. My problem is I need to track some fields coming from HTTP action.

So my output of HTTP action is something like below.

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "x-ms-request-id": "asdfsad",
        "x-ms-client-request-id": "ASFSDF",
        "x-ms-version": "2020-10-02",
        "x-ms-creation-time": "Fri, 05 Nov 2021 12:55:54 GMT",
        "x-ms-lease-status": "unlocked",
        "x-ms-lease-state": "available",
        "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob",
        "x-ms-server-encrypted": "true",
        "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
        "Date": "Wed, 10 Nov 2021 07:52:11 GMT",
        "ETag": "\"SDFGSDGF\"",
        "Server": "Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
        "Content-Length": "1996",
        "Content-MD5": "co+35ZaNw7Be9sgn6YB7OA==",
        "Content-Type": "text/xml",
        "Last-Modified": "Wed, 10 Nov 2021 07:52:11 GMT"
    },
    "body": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<Customer xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"http://company.Schemas\">\r\n  <Company xmlns=\"\">\r\n    <CompanyCode>dk01</CompanyCode>\r\n    <CompanyIdEcom />\r\n    <BillTo>\r\n      <CustomerNo>4004002</CustomerNo>\r\n      <CreditLimit>0</CreditLimit>\r\n      <BlockingLevel>0</BlockingLevel>\r\n      <CurrencyCode>DKK</CurrencyCode>\r\n      <PaymentTerms>N30</PaymentTerms>\r\n      <BillToAddress>\r\n        <PostalCode>2750</PostalCode>\r\n      </BillToAddress>\r\n      <SellTo>\r\n        <SellToAddress>\r\n          <Address>Lautrupbjerg 7 Postbox 99</Address>\r\n          <PostalCode>2750</PostalCode>\r\n          <CountryCode>DK</CountryCode>\r\n        </SellToAddress>\r\n        <ShipTo>\r\n          <Code>5637147732</Code>\r\n          <ShipToAddress>\r\n            <Name>Siemens Medical Instr. Pte.Ltd</Name>\r\n            <City>Singapore</City>\r\n            <PostalCode>139959</PostalCode>\r\n            <CountryCode>SG</CountryCode>\r\n          </ShipToAddress>\r\n        </ShipTo>\r\n        <CustomerNo>4004002</CustomerNo>\r\n        <Name>GN Audio A/S</Name>\r\n        <Searchname>1000-500092,5479</Searchname>\r\n        <CurrencyCode>DKK</CurrencyCode>\r\n        <PrimaryContactEmail />\r\n        <ModeOfDelivery>AIR DHL EX</ModeOfDelivery>\r\n      </SellTo>\r\n    </BillTo>\r\n  </Company>\r\n  <IsDelta xmlns=\"\">true</IsDelta>\r\n</Customer>"
}
```

I am not able to figure out how I can track Customer no from the XML.
`outputs('HTTP-GetBlob')?['body']` (..??????.....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, tracked properties can only reference `@triggerBody`, current `@action()['inputs']` and `@action()['outputs']` - nothing else.

In your case, you'd need to configure tracked properties on your **HTTP-GetBlob** action like this:

```
@xpath(xml(action()['outputs']['body']), '(//CustomerNo/text())[1]')?[0]
```

- experiment with [xpath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#xpath) and adjust it to your liking.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I needed. I tried and it works like a charm. Only thing now if the Logic app fails if the field is null or empty. How should I handle that ?

Comment: Just add the question mark before `[0]`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workarounds that you can try is to convert the XML into JSON then parse it and then use the required parameters accordingly.

Here are the screenshots for your reference
[image]
[image]

Here is the output
[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I need to configure it in Tracked properties and not in logic app actions.